# Solr timestamp woes set timestamp or "create-date" date and not overwrite it

Tags: solr, timestamp

I am trying to set a document created date in Solr4.

```
    <field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>
```

My Schema has the standard timestamp field uncommented and it works great in that I can get the last time I indexed that document (we do full updates on documents 3 times a week) so I can say "Last indexed 3 days ago".

The trouble is because I index full documents via csv, it overwrites this timestamp with every new index.

How can I construct a schema so that I can do the following.

1. Somehow store the date the document was first updated?
2. Store the dates every time I index it (I was thinking I could copy the timestamp file do a new field that is multivalued, not sure if this works).

Most important issue is to set a created date value/field that wont get overwritten or deleted every time I index that document.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the TimestampUpdateProcessor:

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/TimestampUpdateProcessorFactory.html

According to the javadocs:

An update processor that adds a newly generated Date value of "NOW" to any document being added that does not already have a value in the specified field.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I am after, except I need to get of 4.1 and upgrade to 4.4 it seems. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. Well something to look forward to.